# Cover letter with modernCV in LyX

Tags: lyx, moderncv

I created a CV using the modernCV package in LyX and I would like to create a fitting cover letter. I saw a lot of people doing it but following their examples does not work for me.

What I tried:

I opened my finished CV file (so it has all the necessary information in the preamble like e.g. my address) and deleted all the contents in the actual file.
Then I added the following:

```
\clearpage{}

\recipient{Person}{Address} % Letter recipient 
\date{\today} % Letter date 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting 
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title
```

added some text here and finished with

```
\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature
```

But LyX already fails with the recipient and provides "undefined control sequence" errors for any letter related command.
I checked different examples other people provided for a cover letter with modernCV and nobody seems to have changed anything in the preamble to make the CV to a letter. Have I missed something?

Comment: Which version of `moderncv` is installed on your system? Check the log, but you most probably have a version that's too old and didn't yet include the cover letter features. You need moderncv version >= 1.0.0 for cover letters.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks! You are right: LyX 2.0.2 uses modernCV 0.7. So I tried to find out how to add the newest version without breaking the old one. I used this tutorial: http://stefaanlippens.net/customLaTeXclassesinLyX but since the layout file doesn't define a directory for the class, I guess that the class name needs to be unique. So how do I manage to be able to use both modernCV versions in parallel?

Comment: I am afraid it's not (easily) doable. You would probably have to replace `moderncv` v 0.7 with a newer version and rewrite the layout class for LyX. LaTeX can't handle different versions of the same package AFAIK, and the old layout file would most probably not work with the new `moderncv` version...